# Answering a question after it has been flagged as a potential duplicate. Bad form?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, duplicate-answers

**Context**

So, I came across this question: [For Each control not returning all controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34259372/for-each-control-not-returning-all-controls/).  After a quick search, I realized that the question was essentially a duplicate of this question: [VB.NET Loop through controls in a panel skips controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16521332/vb-net-loop-through-controls-in-a-panel-skips-controls), which had answers that would solve OP's question.  So I marked the question to be closed as duplicate. At this point, there were no comments/answers on the question except for the auto-generated comment linking to the duplicate thread.

Some time later (I can't tell anymore, but I believe it was at least 5 minutes later, if not more), an answer gets posted that is essentially the same as the answer(s) found in the duplicate thread.  And even though this user has the necessary rep to also mark the question as to be closed as a duplicate, they don't choose to do so.

**Questions:**

1. Is it considered bad form to answer a question where a clear duplicate has already been flagged by someone else?
2. And if so, are we expected to call out the answerer in some way?  Or, no big deal, and move on...

**Thoughts**

There certainly have been times where I have posted an answer on a question without first bothering to search for a duplicate question out of laziness.

However, where I personally draw the line is if I notice that someone has already gone through the trouble of identifying a duplicate and I agree that it is in fact a duplicate. In such a case, I don't feel comfortable answering the question anymore.  In my eyes, it would be no different than answering a question that has already been answered by someone else, and where my answer doesn't provide any added value.  I think it's bad form.

Also, in the [How should duplicate questions be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled) thread, it says:

> **Should I answer it?**
>
> No, not if you think it's a duplicate. If you don't think the answers on the duplicate question are good enough, write an answer there.
>
> If you don't think the question is a duplicate, then by all means do answer it.

On the other hand, I was provided a link to the following post from Jeff Atwood himself: [Dr. Strangedupe: Or, How I Learned to Stop Worrying And Love Duplication](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/), where in part, it says:

> Furthermore, it's OK for duplicate questions to have duplicate answers. While you could argue that the duplicate questions could all be merged into one question with a "master" set of answers, this is kind of irritating from the perspective of the user looking for an answer.

I don't know that he had the above situation in mind when he wrote this, but it definitely got me thinking about whether it is ok or not to answer a question even if I am already aware of a duplicate thread by the time I answer.

So, if a question has already been flagged as a duplicate, and I agree that it is a duplicate, is it ok to answer anyways?  Or should that be frowned upon?

And if you think it's bad form, should something be done when someone does it anyways?

What do you think?

Comment: If it's been flagged and *you* agree it's a duplicate with perfectly valid answers in the dupe, then I'd say don't waste your time answering. If you feel like a particular answer in the dupe is worth highlighting, then maybe comment. If somebody else has answered, then don't worry about it. They may not have seen the dupe before they submitted their answer. Or they might not agree that it's a dupe. Or they might feel there is some particular aspect of this question that is different. Of course, if they've straight up lifted an answer from the dupe, you could probably comment and / or flag it.

Comment: see here for instance http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37466/give-an-incentive-for-finding-duplicate-questions/37478#37478

Comment: Mark as duplicate. Then answer as well as you can, before the rest of the rep-trolls get in there. At least then by the time it gets closed, it has good info. Until SO give us a way to clean up duplicates properly and remove the mess, that is the best way I have to deal with the problem. Cos this whole belief in downvoting and closing duplicates, it doesn't really keep the junk off the site.

Comment: I would think you should take into consideration the title and minutiae.  For example, say someone asks a question about a foreach in C# and it gets flagged as a duplicate in VB.  A lot of people (myself included) won't go look at the VB duplicate because they don't touch VB.  Therefore it's not considered a duplicate because hey, different language.  Not saying it's the right mentality, but it is what it is.  In such a case, I'd likely go ahead and answer it in the different language even if it were considered a duplicate by someone else.

Comment: And for the record, I am one of those rep-trolls @RichardLeMesurier mentioned.  Kinda blah that all of the "easy" answers are already taken and us newbies have to scavenge what's left. Maybe a more streamlined rep system is in order (limit max rep for a question/answer to 50 points)?  At this point it seems like most questions are just old questions with a slightly different spin. ;)

Comment: @Bardicer In retrospect I should have been more specific. By taking time on Meta, you are unlikely one of those I meant - to be more specific there are lots of very bad answers to duplicates that continue to spread untruths, and like a virus this misinformation takes over the site. Unless someone with the Power of Truth and Knowledge puts a correct answer down first. I only hope that as you took the time to reply, you are also a seeker of truth and try to answer questions with true information. If not, well then troll away ;-)

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier Haha yes, I do try to be as accurate as possible.  In fact if I give an incorrect answer for whatever reason (even if the question was initially not the real question) and it's pointed out, I will go ahead and delete my answer even if it was upvoted and/or accepted.  Quality over quantity.  Unfortunately if someone answers a simple question about say string manipulation, they can rack up thousands of reputation and are perceived as knowing more than someone who has answered more niche and esoteric questions that don't get upvoted as much.

Comment: @Bardicer I hear you re niche. Was a BlackBerry developer a while back... and we all know how popular those are.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, I'd say it's bad form, at least if the answer is indeed "essentially the same as the answer(s) found in the duplicate thread."

That said, in general, the only things you can or should *do* about it are:

1. downvote, and/or
2. leave a comment explaining why such answers are bad form, so that others will hopefully not upvote it.

As a bonus of sorts, leaving a (polite and well written) comment explaining why posting such answers is bad form *may* even convince the author of the answer to stop doing it.  Do [pay attention to your tone](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) when writing such comments, though; rude or accusatory comments rarely if ever convince anyone of anything.

If it looks like the answer actually includes content copied from the other thread [without attribution](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing), that may count as plagiarism.  In that case, you may want to [flag it for moderator attention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160071/what-to-do-when-plagiarism-is-discovered), at least if you can't easily fix the attribution yourself by editing, or if you suspect that it's not an isolated incident.

Comment: I'm really opposed to any solution that involves "downvote and comment." The downvote already establishes bad tone - it's as if the comment begins with "no offense, but..." so now you've put someone in a bad mood and invited them to argue with you.

Comment: @djechlin: You don't *have* to do either of those things. If you feel the answerer might be more receptive to your comment without the downvote (or if you're worried that you might be encouraging sympathy upvotes), you can just comment but leave the answer unvoted. IME, a well written comment explaining the issues with an answer is still the most effective method (short of deletion) for preventing undeserved upvotes. Or, conversely, if you don't feel like taking the time to write a comment, you could just downvote and move on. Or do neither.

Comment: i wouldn't downvote the answer if it is a good answer (disregarding the whole duplicate thing). But, I might leave a comment about it being bad form, maybe with a link to the dupe answer, if it exists.

Comment: @Jakar: If it really just repeats the answers already given in the duplicate thread, then I would say that it's not a very good answer. (And if it adds something new that hasn't been mentioned in the duplicate thread yet, then it's arguably in the wrong place, at least assuming that the questions really *are* exact duplicates.) Whether that's enough to make it deserve a downvote is, of course, a subjective and often case-by-case decision.

Comment: I'm not comfortable with the practice of punishment downvotes on answers that are technically correct. They can be misleading to the OP and future readers who are trying to find the best answers to their questions. Feel free to comment on the answer, _especially_ in cases of plagiarism. Actually, I guess in cases of flagrant plagiarism a downvote _is_ justified if accompanied by an explanatory comment. And certainly downvote the question for lack of research.

Answer (score 8):

People tend to rely on what gains points/experience/reputation more than what people decide on meta when deciding a course of action. When I find myself in this situation I often post a terse answer then link to the one in the duplicate, for the blunt reason that someone else will probably post their answer and get upvotes for it, and I don't like that.

You could downvote someone who answers a duplicate but I would caution against this: it won't be apparent why so will just be confusing, and if you explain your political motivation, you're inviting yourself into a long rantish internet argument. Better to leave it be.

If you're not obsessed with reputation like the rest of us, then you found the answer, helped the person and community, so who cares about the rest, move on.

Comment: I admit that I'm often tempted to answer the question myself, even after flagging the duplicate, for the exact reason you mention.  But I feel guilty doing so, because then I would be no better than the next person who does the same thing, and I wouldn't be leading be example.  But I do share the sentiment :)

Comment: Yes, answer it - cos otherwise someone who doesn't know as well as you do, **will answer** and then the garbage answers will spread.

Comment: @sstan: If you really do want to post an answer, but feel guilty about it, you could always make your answer a Community Wiki so that you won't gain rep from it.

Comment: @Ilmari: Yeah, I have considered that option, and maybe I should do that.  I'm know I'm overthinking this, but another reason why I prefer not to answer is because I see it as my way of encouraging those who ask questions to realize that they should check for duplicates before asking a new question.  If I quickly provide a duplicate answer, even if it doesn't give me any rep, I fear I would encourage OP to effortlessly keep asking questions without checking for duplicates first.

Comment: @sstan *actually* a community wiki just saying "this is a duplicate - here is the link" may be a strategy. I never thought of that, I might try it and see if it goes badly.

Comment: @djechlin Good Idea! It might accomplish what I want while still appeasing the powers that be. Add that to your answer - it is a useful idea.

Answer (score -2):

It's generally not appropriate to answer a duplicated question. The best approach is as said above to downvote the question and provide reasoning for why the downvote was valid in this circumstance. A duplicated question can be very wasteful and indicates a lack of knowledge with the formal protocols and procedures one should utilize when posting to the forum.

Comment: To be clear, I'm not worried about the duplicate question itself, and I don't think all duplicate questions are bad either.  So I generally won't downvote the question unless it's absolutely obvious that no effort whatsoever was made to perform a simple Google search.

Comment: AAaaand, duplicate questions can be GOOD. If somebody posts a dupe question, it's either a) because they're lazy and didn't look (very hard) for an answer or b) because they looked for an answer and couldn't find it. If it's b, then the dupe question will likely help future searchers find the original question.