# Funky way to deal with a duplicate question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close, community-wiki

So just came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37591700/how-to-handle-unique-key-constraint-in-insert-or-update) and was wondering what to think of the way it was dealt with as a duplicate.

It was just a bit out of the norm so wanted to ask about it.

A user identified a potential duplicate question and close voted. Then proceeded to copy the answer from that question to the new question with the following:

> Answer copied from Question XYZ (Consider marking this question as a duplicate of that post and then deleting this answer).

The answer was then converted to community wiki, so it looks like the user had good intentions and wasn't hunting reputation.

My thoughts are that the answer wasn't really required as it was already linked in the close vote comment.

**Related post:**

[Answering a question after it has been flagged as a potential duplicate. Bad form?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312312/answering-a-question-after-it-has-been-flagged-as-a-potential-duplicate-bad-for)

Comment: I say we delete the answer and let the close process work.  They did make the answer a CW so they gain nothing but it still leaves a bad taste in my mouth with just copying and pasting the answer with no other addition.

Comment: I agree with the title of this post. My way of handling it was *funky*.  I did it as a result of a suggestion I got in a comment under this [answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/312319/4955425) from my meta post [Answering a question after it has been flagged as a potential duplicate. Bad form?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312312/answering-a-question-after-it-has-been-flagged-as-a-potential-duplicate-bad-for).  Not sure how I feel about it either, but I wanted to try it at least once and see how it worked out.  I'm glad it got a little attention :)

Comment: @sstan If you've close-voted a dupe, and your target's a good match, but there are no gold badgers or other domain experts around to close it, and the question's attracting useless answers, then you can always post a close-vote request in [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570). If your dupe target _is_ good then even those who aren't experts in that problem domain will easily see that, so they can close-vote with confidence. Of course, it's better if a gold badger can hammer it, to avoid wasting votes, but they aren't always available, especially in low-traffic tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right. The answer is superfluous.

The user should be:

- flagging to close [if they have >= 15 but < 3,000 rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285766) (note prior to 2016-10-12 only users with > 50 rep could do that).
- voting to close if they have > 3,000 rep. This automatically inserts a comment.

Comment: thanks for the late response... doing some housekeeping?! :-)

Comment: @Tanner - possibly. I couldn't possibly comment :)

Comment: [since 2016-10-12](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285766) users with rep >= 15 and < 50 are able to flag posts as duplicates